# Enter a two-dimensional array in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, we could enter in a cell for example `={1;2;3;4}` (a `one-dimensional array`), then `ctrl+shift+enter` to enter an array:

[image]

Does anyone know if it is possible to enter `a two-dimensional array in a single cell`?

Comment: `={1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8}` The `,` is for columns the `;` for rows.

Comment: I see... it does not work in my Excel for Mac, but I believe it will work in Excel for Windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @ScottCraner suggested:

> `={1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8}` The `,` is for columns the `;` for rows.